# How to remove specific items from a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to remove items on `List<ReplyTile>` with `id = 001`.. ?

```
final List<ReplyTile> _replytile = <ReplyTile>[];

_replytile.add(
    ReplyTile(
        member_photo: 'photo',
        member_id: '001',
        date: '01-01-2018',
        member_name: 'Denis',
        id: '001',
        text: 'hallo..'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 203, accepted):

`removeWhere` allows to do that:

```
replytile.removeWhere((item) => item.id == '001')
```

See also [List Dartdoc](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/List/removeWhere.html)

Comment: What if we have List<CustomWidget> . Can we remove dynamic added widget ?

Comment: @HarshBhavsar not sure what you mean. Have you tried? What problem did you run into?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310614/remove-index-wise-customwidget-from-listwidget-in-flutter

Comment: what if item.id == '001' is asynchronous?

Comment: How could this be async? Is `id` an async getter? Using https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Stream/Stream.fromIterable.html, https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Stream/where.html, https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html should work: `Stream.fromIterable(replytile).asyncMap((item) async => {"item": item, "id": await item.id }).where((m) => m.id != '001').map((m) => m.item)).toList()`. Not tested and you might need to add some type annotations.

Comment: FYI. If you're working with a List<dynamic> array, then it will be: `replytile.removeWhere((item) => item["id"] == '001')`

Answer (score 33):

In your case this works:

```
replytile.removeWhere((item) => item.id == '001');
```

For list with specific datatype such as int, remove also works.Eg:

```
List id = [1,2,3];
id.remove(1);
```

Comment: listname.remove(item); 

Works very fine for me!!

Answer (score 23):

```
//For removing specific item from a list with the attribute value
replytile.removeWhere((item) => item.id == '001') 

//Remove item by specifying the position of the item in the list
replytile.removeAt(2)   

//Remove last item from the list
replytile.removeLast()

//Remove a range of items from the list
replytile.removeRange(2,5)
```

Answer (score 8):

**This also works**

```
_listofTaskUI.removeAt(_quantity);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here the simple list functions with sample output**

> Consider the sample list

```
List sampleList = ["001", "002", "003"];
```

> Here some add to list functions with output

```
//Add to list

  sampleList.add("004");
//Output: 001 002 003 004

//Add to specific index

  sampleList.insert(0, "005");
//Output: 005 001 002 003
```

> Here  the list remove functions with examples consider the same sample list

```
sampleList.removeWhere((item) => item.id == '003');
//Output: 001 002

//Remove item from secific index

  sampleList.removeAt(2);
//Output: 001 003

//Remove item from last

  sampleList.removeLast();
//Output: 001 002

//Remove items between range

  sampleList.removeRange(1, 2);
//Output: 002 003
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a generic list

```
List<int> sliderBtnIndex = [];//Your list

sliderBtnIndex.remove(int.tryParse(index)); //remove
```

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes more reliable to create a new list from an existing one.  Modifying a list could create pass-by-reference errors.  If a list is passed as a parameter, calling `remove` might alter the list outside of your function thereby creating unexpected results and hard to find bugs.

To create a new list from an old one just filter the results

```
var newList = oldList.where((x) => x.id != id)
```

or use something like `whereNot` in DartX

```
var newList = oldList.whereNot((x) => x.id == id)
```

That being said creating a new list would allocate more memory every time you create a new list.  An alternative would be to create a new list before you modify it, for example:

```
var safeList = [...oldList];
safeList.removeWhere((item) => item.id == '001')
```